# How to normalize column names with '.1' in the column name and not drop any other characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df that looks like this:

```
col1_test   col1_test.1
abc          NaN
```

How do I drop only the `.1` while keeping all the other characters in the column name?

current code to drop `.1`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.extract(r'\.?', expand=False)
```

but this is dropping the other characters in the column name like underscore.

New df:

```
col1_test   col1_test
abc          NaN
```

Once this part is set, I will merge the columns using this:

```
df = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).first()
```

Comment: Why do you need duplicate columns in a Dataframe?

Comment: @Vishnudev this is a bad dataset I got, eventually I will merge them using this `df = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).first()`

Comment: Do you need the `.1` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not recommended because it becomes difficult to index specific columns when there are duplicate headers.

A better solution, however, since trying to perform a `groupby`, would be to pass a callable.

```
df
  col1_test  col1_test.1
0       abc          NaN

df.groupby(by=lambda x: x.rsplit('.', 1)[0], axis=1).first()

  col1_test
0       abc
```

---

For reference, you'd remove column suffixes with `str.replace`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'\.\d+$', '')
```

You can also use `str.rsplit`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit('.', 1).str[0]
df
   col1_test  col1_test
0        abc        NaN
```